# Append header to requests from Rails controller to same controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have previously only used rails for webservices, and am trying to mimic my token authentication scheme with actual views. I have a `User` model that is tied to an `AccessToken` model which has a token which expires. When a request is made to the server it looks for `request.headers['Wyr-User-Token']` and then looks up the user with this token. This works fine when I curl to the webpage and set the header myself as I would if I were making an app.

My question is, when the user is logged in a variable `@logged_in_user` is set (first set in the `/users/login` route that skips token authentication. After this I would like all requests from these controllers append the `@logged_in_user`'s token to requests coming from the rails app. I was thinking some sort of `after_filter` with code like this:

```
def set_headers
   if(@logged_in_user)
      request.headers['Wyr-User-Token'] = @logged_in_user.access_token.token
   end
end
```

When I do my `redirect_to` though, the header is not in the request! How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is not possible, using `redirect_to` and instead what you need to do is in your authentication setup pull the token from either the session or header depending on request type.